# java.sql.SQLException: Output parameters have not yet been processed. Call getMoreResults()

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am getting error while calling stored procedure having 3 output parameters. I am using Tomcat JNDI configuration to make a connection.

Following is my Code in java.

```
  package com.ef.clients.ptcl;
  import java.sql.CallableStatement;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  import javax.naming.Context;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;

  import com.audium.server.AudiumException;
  import com.audium.server.session.ActionElementData;
  import com.audium.server.voiceElement.ActionElementBase;

  public class GetCallerCountNew extends ActionElementBase {

 DataSource ds; 
public GetCallerCountNew(){
    Context initialContext;
    try{
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/CallerCount");
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}

CallableStatement proc = null;
Connection connection = null;
String ani = null; 
String dnis = null;
@Override
public void doAction(String arg0, ActionElementData data) throws AudiumException {


    try {   
            long time_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            data.addToLog("Entered in getCallerCount class:",null);
            ani = (String) data.getSessionData("ani");
            dnis = (String) data.getSessionData("dnis");

                //going to get connection.
            if (ds == null) {
                data.addToLog("DataSource isn't established.", null);
                throw new AudiumException("DataSource isn't established.");
            }
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            if (connection == null) {
                data.addToLog("Connection isn't established.", null);
                throw new AudiumException("Connection isn't established.");
            }

            // Reading Caller Count
            int WirelineCountToday;
            int WireLessCountToday;
            int TotalCountToday;
            proc = null;
            proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call Custom_Db_Expertqueue_GetCallerCount(?,?,?,?,?) }");

            data.addToLog("Setting ANI: ",ani);
            String parameters = "ANI: " + ani + " DNIS: " + dnis;
            data.addToLog("Calling Stroed proceedure with parameters . ", parameters);

            proc.setString(1, ani); 
            proc.setString(2, dnis); 
            proc.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            proc.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            proc.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

            data.addToLog("Stroed proceedure executed successfully. ", null);



            int out = proc.executeUpdate();

            // getting output parameters from strored proceedure
            WirelineCountToday=proc.getInt(3);//  getInt(1);
            WireLessCountToday=proc.getInt(4);
            TotalCountToday=proc.getInt(5);

            // setting session values 
            data.setSessionData("WirelineCount", WirelineCountToday);
            data.setSessionData("WirelessCount", WireLessCountToday);
            data.setSessionData("TotalCount", TotalCountToday);

            data.addToLog("WirelineCountToday Value Retrieved:", Integer.toString(WirelineCountToday));
            data.addToLog("TotalCountToday Value Retrieved:", Integer.toString(TotalCountToday));
            data.addToLog("WireLessCountToday Value Retrieved:", Integer.toString(WireLessCountToday));

            data.addToLog("Returned value from proceedure is:", Integer.toString(out));
            data.addToLog("for Information.... SUCCESS = 0, FAILURE=1", null);


            long time_2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            data.addToLog("Total Execution Time is: ", time_2-time_1+" ms");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      { data.addToLog("Exeption while creating connection: ", e.toString()); }

      finally {
          data.addToLog("Going to close connection and callStatement.", null);
          try {
              if(proc !=null){
                  proc.close();
                  data.addToLog("callStatement Closed Successfully.", null);
              }
              else{
                  data.addToLog("callStatement is null..", null);
              }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            data.addToLog("ERROR WHILE TRYING TO CLOSE STATEMENT. MESSAGE IS: ", e.toString());
          }
          proc = null;
          try {
              if(connection != null) { 
                  connection.close();
                  data.addToLog("Connection closed successfully.", null);
              }
              else{
                  data.addToLog("Connection is null..", null);
              }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            data.addToLog("ERROR WHILE TRYING TO CLOSE CONNECTINO. MESSAGE IS: ", e.toString());
          }
          connection = null;    
    }
}
 }
```

Following is stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Custom_Db_Expertqueue_GetCallerCount]

@ANI varchar(50),
@DNIS varchar(50),
@WirelineCount varchar(10)out,
@WirelessCount varchar(10) out,
@TotalCallCount varchar(10) out
 AS
 BEGIN

IF(@DNIS='45236' OR @DNIS='45412')
BEGIN
    SELECT @WirelineCount = COUNT(*) FROM [ptcl_repetitivecaller].[dbo].[Custom_Db_ExpertQueue_CallCount]
    Where ANI =@ANI
    AND (DNIS= '45236' OR DNIS ='45236') and AGENT_TRANSFER=0
    AND (SG IN('PSTN','BB','GPON','IPTV','PnNet','CallCard','VAS'))
    AND cast (CALL_TIME as Date) = cast (GETDATE() as DATE)

    SELECT @WirelessCount = COUNT(*) FROM [ptcl_repetitivecaller].[dbo].[Custom_Db_ExpertQueue_CallCount]
    WHERE ANI = @ANI AND (DNIS='45236' OR DNIS='45236') 
    AND AGENT_TRANSFER=0
    AND (SG IN('Test','WLL','OUTAGE_EVO')) 
    AND cast (CALL_TIME as Date) = cast (GETDATE() as DATE)
    SET @TotalCallCount = cast(@WirelineCount as int) + cast(@WirelessCount as int)
END
ELSE  IF(@DNIS='45236' OR @DNIS='45410' OR @DNIS='45218' OR @DNIS='45418')
BEGIN
    SELECT @WirelineCount = COUNT(*) FROM [ptcl_repetitivecaller].[dbo].[Custom_Db_ExpertQueue_CallCount]
    WHERE ANI = @ANI AND (DNIS='45210' OR DNIS='45410' OR DNIS='45218' OR DNIS='45418') 
    AND (SG IN('PSTN','BB','WIRELINE','SALES','WIRELINE','GPON')) 
    AND AGENT_TRANSFER=1
    AND cast (CALL_TIME as Date) = cast (GETDATE() as DATE)

    SELECT @WirelessCount = COUNT(*) FROM [ptcl_repetitivecaller].[dbo].[Custom_Db_ExpertQueue_CallCount]
    WHERE ANI = @ANI AND (DNIS='45210' OR DNIS='45410' OR DNIS='45218' OR DNIS='45418') 
    AND (SG IN('EVO','WIRLESS','WIRELESS')) 
    AND AGENT_TRANSFER=1
    AND cast (CALL_TIME as Date) = cast (GETDATE() as DATE)

    SET @TotalCallCount = cast(@WirelineCount as int) + cast(@WirelessCount as int)
    END
END
```

Most of the time i am getting the above mentioned error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have solved this problem by creating a new stored procedure. I think there was something wrong with stored procedure creation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the output value was getting NULL instead of a big int value(Due to no records in the query that i mapped to the output variable). So at the end of the sproc i checked if output value is null and assigned it to an int value like -1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay. This occurs when you try to access the results of the stored procedure before actually executing a call to it. For example, running this would cause the error that you are getting:

```
        // getting output parameters from strored proceedure
        WirelineCountToday=proc.getInt(3);//  getInt(1);
        WireLessCountToday=proc.getInt(4);
        TotalCountToday=proc.getInt(5);

        int out = proc.executeUpdate();
```

Also, for select statements I would recommend using:

```
        int out = proc.execute();
```

Comment: This explaines why the error is occuring but it doesn't answer the question how to resolve it.